# How to get Facebook post id with Facebook-Actionscript SDK?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, facebook-graph-api, desktop-application

After I upload a photo on a desktop facebook application i need to store it's post id in a database. From the facebook ActionScript SDK documentation:

api()   method

```
public static function api(method:String, callback:Function, params:* = null, requestMethod:String = GET):void
```

Makes a new request on the Facebook Graph API.

Parameters [...]

```
callback:Function — Method that will be called when this request is complete The handler must have the signature of callback(result:Object, fail:Object); On success, result will be the object data returned from Facebook. On fail, result will be null and fail will contain information about the error.
```

So I implemented my callback function as follows:

```
    protected function handleUploadComplete(response:Object, fail:Object):void{

            status = (response) ? 'Success' : 'Error';
            var file:File = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath("Log.txt");
            var stream:FileStream = new FileStream();
            stream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);
            stream.writeUTFBytes(response.toString());
            stream.close();

        }
```

The problem is that response or response.toString() both return "[object Object]", and I was hoping for something more like "id: somenumber".
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If everything has worked the `response` will contain a property called `id` that is your post ID.  Otherwise it will be null and the `fail` object will be populated.

```
protected function handleUploadComplete(response:Object, fail:Object):void
{
    var status:Boolean = response != null;
    if(status) var id:String = response.id;
    //do whatever you want
}
```